# 400 bad request

Tags: php, http-status-code-400

Здравствуйте, хотел бы узнать, почему отдаётся **400 bad request** при таком количестве данных, хотя написано, что 1000 максимум, а тут 900 и беда, а получается работает только на 300. Пример при большом количестве данных:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?uids=178418127,156650173,32606326,1228141,221541737,27831980,188288024,209382473,220825113,178630754,51645663,31204856,42935142,98827681,106306003,210549889,128104885,97481789,76146792,31484710,176870355,31036196,197164392,57103791,220238403,224583753,204301811,77842403,173602112,145033478,180336271,137625873,173532865,12973021,218079648,167518213,20623613,169221373,155467187,209224173,197003468,177549148,146091174,212607690,222080343,196071878,101192977,201706837,128309819,195321465,214170515,93052339,32063028,178447228,198465857,208758356,149031605,174240506,87196303,115957563,120227227,168370180,215771272,215553489,219254768,214225102,182775716,184079668,182721003,58092010,208969486,222963292,186551038,185596318,197150571,35011572,31216491,202838148,224533481,169865389,208435226,212103116,97706267,163291287,88701663,143219350,177058269,136395822,217278802,216536542,127469081,107744625,118723555,94767467,9030095,95602740,145003388,65425233,94368184,225533832,199874016,214540197,217630091,217663332,139342630,133799874,107750196,148340976,192975816,39143581,151021367,195305929,172900959,80056619,225486572,152589473,210330119,154289707,121750630,199499113,224396964,121981402,158048005,199983691,209308073,220724415,225288540,59119533,165841517,151182649,189025551,219385877,14394933,154035402,136967504,225536368,195516433,147100848,172785062,208708119,57295378,138184813,133648809,196192374,187001815,174033932,166687627,224635107,216918983,198734489,113464846,160936891,154577402,221451359,62805834,221758475,208751791,19745905,158717006,211616283,140795443,215399968,152435044,210932668,215802245,224499290,224660585,152297211,193393430,204963186,155387722,219381809,221989149,211738181,223290908,177159949,79849952,177411948,222164006,19476946,186518048,190672915,64299368,156332632,169827499,216976956,112863399,211092113,110419285,206755785,141367968,90080138,220566980,140821296,220247237,214469387,156832497,78036645,135380849,169062739,17143894,222201270,110592793,218009897,216440627,191647927,78087637,213822748,198691744,150899118,186431155,204863138,178433338,51931506,13573798,166684243,210761292,175835743,170547859,181447817,200104524,150494744,183992933,92142098,102834437,90563407,222446753,178691047,210170295,52926190,16396928,98468358,194332941,175702483,221417828,161430957,87084544,220095786,222902708,12238087,24309176,224377381,136270165,162069875,196749480,217351125,173163653,213263378,90004858,199558056,105589943,218524819,146829707,214316437,213525694,217520549,82295680,219417313,149416515,184979263,33553326,225604795,60168308,181886539,87705773,139947744,180211942,22405625,225755808,94587034,171440153,67579073,136448948,32670220,93121568,134679089,154241883,148227374,194188745,161698892,24380238,191028637,221678512,134856365,188479097,44909512,66883254,200169556,158220085,195474678,154170795,221162085,195319688,141368059,94251643,70888848,104408339,34020326,56424791,59953783,207005042,204796004,222464525,199424899,61825167,58143109,204956531,159707327,209693909,137577875,185990815,93152712,56461247,398019,9656600,16286794,161606601,215060252,95941190,225915127,221254713,150488077,116367098,192698478,21928469,82158153,179127454,181388932,218896166,42271109,159302927,225874966,154173130,135805603,225460369,193935347,208365176,64539374,90452623,225152833,222595052,208814250,225226461,121218601,150964369,153870071,141826739,201428877,189122992,12883000,224442352,182377757,153547036,85081137,40699738,176343118,28058003,77939670,226097963,217566915,144368754,117706548,225272035,226127865,226128086,226128142,225953688,225953822,182608517,199543857,145680806,217354232,161828008,225954000,186102553,225954295,225954558,225954785,225955120,225955296,225955678,225955720,143193507,225954168,151030015,139123846,186024875,170365773,221460321,136183939,162561025,226103894,225955938,225956004,225957022,225958080,225958315,225958472,133216697,95089367,209685447,222263939,187419044,217869342,172868251,47865615,121800982,210540439,158082738,142178208,97164087,220019401,222310612,215241949,120659767,222069066,1997392,218829146,197768073,184166503,220092977,86885961,206687008,147110162,226255315,220762976,217289381,192336471,56194999,138877397,203169942,166345447,206279295,164278484,145476907,118808181,177185612,219293384,58052565,20277985,210879128,202200764,34730590,169190977,225061437,56517798,219140699,79247354,183343551,145962620,221512224,148126774,156802828,207827744,179024181,120228386,123459150,210249323,215084918,46082995,54370141,44874829,180560888,212212355,211582948,206596605,217189275,219596516,182356677,210556827,166956336,195348901,197120003,44083064,132746224,119900259,208899295,205127885,107989857,183320988,165258416,82243247,197559640,42713117,208587675,86375374,29481295,137493969,226072112,87989067,220112090,52884502,151675554,191862429,189809290,169573982,224615915,80943763,226406616,144538758,226560493,165316329,160605695,139220065,144190593,147930334,224101386,225242915,177949748,224465859,155123103,225924561,221815748,38150341,153915063,193100456,210121146,156844203,214092399,186246236,123818266,218313044,213234286,111077531,206442428,10649319,223088273,225002593,146280792,226675872,78755351,154172773,163039985,17622277,222107789,56296506,169636796,151876794,143246573,146492707,155684860,200573664,174140037,222391134,134727320,208077706,154706629,220223540,188958721,174662558,62772176,89385922,171526784,76466466,211815486,180815225,133169851,132257176,178664351,222141377,182627276,185128967,217053043,225232555,196279535,198760447,91506891,225489276,226977120,141857682,106080403,163204747,138220713,223257618,225378431,214574201,215661710,198669589,226966315,211844767,163670783,222667778,5672332,84131306,172182178,155437603,221358066,163756222,226970686,225214443,226962441,137386786,94738770,225494732,2703965,33699524,186584972,226037356,192715014,200377791,222192426,212663758,19555889,158224397,83009289,153515752,157526511,80212430,227208634,205088102,161461609,227175492,146096565,114469130,164193028,227227074,209283185,126388437,59556444,173100388,213851017,214050217,46605148,226882746,156660313,216870942,227144177,119777000,149186175,22539795,227364627,175468473,128056845,147155059,178382559,133617774,185014472,171503174,145494441,222460965,226759288,197883198,18797477,223408292,164789825,90128944,220296146,163354289,182698517,36931127,180953325,159594965,24338151,216664436,167354539,227591628,226867366,85338750,226488828,168353629,124420040,226594551,146293139,227072551,135472603,227588916,152697747,72125665,1032506,192890857,188576220,222225547,209065839,166560047,221558327,213519489,215137197,222153256,50751987,214991240,45043639,213652202,227834429,151617428,176767077,43406724,227632312,1791799,163704450,226521996,227911142,78124233,227878820,165101787,147025739,12311367,194346033,215742873,173938996,172838334,134179837,151713181,149098572,137358674,211857385,228023174,75942840,32631564,207828474,54841036,206047879,65240550,1516687,141795207,44100292,137260688,224075593,220508426,72421528,175555151,140463345,42791004,61663944,164789699,228136827,228137161,228137533,228138197,228138938,228139465,228139710,139926288,38013855,220148852,197614560,159553624,73917010,146287313,57756052,174326492,220505326,228249207,216561451,161137714,216835181,45723778,31184918,197697593,102187453,220550951,212197754,228140036,228140662,228141128,222758605,224395847,228141464,190620919,62240065,178908873,176889281,117560081,195325821,163565807,55068555,131788725,96772882,128346962,216948618,173523644,175720413,212967846,28285903,15873843,156611940,209874308,223943191,213339282,5520276,191623341,170621896,135660203,140378541,9749376,84121944,20083308,226151281,217766756,139551609,43446714,144788193,150562973,54664329,224538957,122325214,191062871,225502361,84994859,6246588,143914993,41572261,174524258,201274639,204454167,201046499,163681372,204209855,198122183,221034196,122317110,223332454,115961359,125843144,123563785,170557063,227736289,132622729,137501852,213355904,179147722,152408741,205847789,215947294,166708846,56680156,216346842,197493222,216946524,156656783,228142026,94268621,224805682,222852209,171063315,129407311,72907291,202238082,211778245,151151750,218379014,210330322,82448127,197618416,222778930,79681253,199863327,202360915,238409,163241030,24913032,214786676,86430538,196705476,19038583,17199698,226584247,96273451,220947114,116713936,211606843,154856175,220612650,39815692,209458874,226090365,228559950,182242923,87038526,112825444,187088617,209708792,64321356,223293781,98901601,209951539,158670599,152192683,228622734,31725985,217883431,189137371,127455931,58838175,49764940,123639103,227993117,134623789,119521824,228543831,98404625,140452190,99316680,203044881,105841382,224105655,226148890,226149559,210755225,226149800,226149885&access_token=323
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего сервер не ожидает такой длины GET параметров. Загружайте порциями. Например по 100 пользователей.

Answer (score 0):

На случай если кто-то еще наткнётся на этот вопрос: длина **GET** запросов к VK API действительно ограничены ихним *nginx'ом*, а не 1000 как сказано в документации. А вот **POST** этого дополнительного ограничения нет!

Comment: Нигде больше не встречал такой отвратительной документации как ВКонтакте. Разрабы ВК, покайтесь!

Answer (score 0):

Из доки на [VK Api](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests): По длине для GET запросов

> Если вы будете передавать большие данные (больше 2 килобайт), следует использовать POST.